# Ruby on Rails + Active_Record: How do I include child counts in result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I figured out how to include the children in a to_json result by creating an as_json method in the folder model.

```
def as_json(options={ })
  super(
          options.merge(
                  :include => {
                          :children => { }
                  }
          )
  )
end
```

The above code gives me a list of the children, but what I want is to include the count not the list of children.  I also want to filter it to only "Active" children.

I can't seem to figure out an efficient way to do this.

I'm using the below code to return a list of folders.

```
def index
  @folders = Folder.all(:order => "Name")

  respond_with(@folders) do |format|
    format.jsonp { render :json => @folders, :callback => params[:callback] }
  end
end
```

Finally, I want to make sure the count comes back in all results not just json.  json is the most important but I do want to make sure it's in the others as well.

I thought I would be able to add the count to each of the folders returned by @folders after the query by using .size.  However, that doesn't seem to work...

Next I started looking into adding a method to the Folder model such as...

```
def child_count
  write_attribute(:child_count, children.size)
end
```

But after looking at it I realized that's not really going to work...

So now I'm looking into :select to do some sql magic... but I really don't want to go that route if there's a cleaner way.

Tips appreciated!

Comment: Okay I figured out the answer but I can't answer my own question because my reputation is less than 100.  So here's a link to the answer on my blog...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `child_count` method that returns the number of children and then use the [`:methods`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) option for `as_json`:

```
def as_json(options = { })
    super(options.merge(:methods => :child_count))
end
```

You might want to be a bit more careful with that `merge` though, if there is a `:methods` already in `options` you'll overwrite it; something like this might serve you better than a straight merge:

```
def add_child_count(options)
    options[:methods] = [ options[:methods], :child_count ].flatten.compact.uniq
    options
end

def as_json(options = { })
    super(add_child_count(options))
end
```

For XML, you do pretty much the same thing with [`to_xml`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#method-i-to_xml) instead of `as_json`.

Comment: I just figured this out.  I was trying to answer my own question but my rep is too low and it wouldn't let me.  Thanks though that's exactly what I figured out!

Comment: Oh one problem... that only adds it to the json.  I thought I could create an as_xml method to add it to xml as well, but that's not working.  However, I did find that I can use to_xml for those that need this same functionality.

Comment: @Altonymous: The XML should be same deal. I also added a "paranoia" update for the `merge` handling that you might be interested in, just in case someone says `x.as_json(:methods => :aha!)` in the future.